# What is an "integrated self-opening load switch" actually called?

Tags: automotive, protection, over-voltage-protection

Here is a throw-away circuit to illustrate the behaviour I'm looking for:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0V5rC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Basically a load switch, but during an over-voltage event instead of shorting the input (which in this case is a car battery, so that won't go well) open the input. No regulation, just protection prior to regulation. What is the actual name for this circuit, and what is a more common topology? Do manufacturers offer integrated versions of this thing? Is it modifiable to have the same opening behaviour on reverse voltage?

I've found some examples though (a) they're a little pricy and (b) perhaps more complex than I have in mind:

- The LTC1153 called an "auto-reset circuit breaker";
- The LTC4365 called an "overvoltage supply protection controller"; or
- The STBP120 called an "overvoltage protection device".

After more research, the only prevailing term that seems somewhat common across multiple devices is "lockout", as in UVLO (under-voltage lockout) or OVLO (over-voltage lockout). This seems more common as a feature of other devices like regulators than a description of a stand-alone device.

Perhaps I'm better off sticking with a discrete solution.

Comment: I'd call it an over-voltage isolator or lock-out circuit. You can also use a low-drop-out buck regulator for the same thing.

Comment: TI has an appnote: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva681a/snva681a.pdf
In general, this is called "load dump protection."

Comment: You would need two (series) MOSFETs to protect against overvoltage and reverse voltage. So double the voltage drop. I would also suggest adding some hysteresis otherwise there is an range of input voltages at which M1 will dissipate a lot of power.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Rather than two series MOSFETs, could I not just have one whose gate has two different disable branches?

Comment: No, because the body diode will only permit a MOSFET to block in one direction.